# Should I use XSLT or Java to transform my XML documents?

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I've got to transform a bunch of XML documents to another format.

From what I can tell I can use XSLT or Java and an XML reader/writer. From past experience I remember XSLT being a slow, uphill struggle.

Any recommendations as to whether I would be better off using XSLT vs Java + XML reader/writer to make these new XML files?

Speed of transformation does not matter to me. This process will happen once for each of the 20 xml files that I need to process. I don't have to do this on an ongoing basis - in other words this process is throw-away.

The output XML will be simmilar, simple XML. No swank.

Comment: I'd say it depends on whether or not your program will be the only thing that does the transformation. That is, if I understand the question correctly, and I rarely do. :)

Comment: I just added a comment - This is a one shot thing so yea this is the only thing that does the transformation.

Comment: not very constructive at the moment. how complex is required transformation? what's resulting format? java's xml processing may be verbose and time-consuming, so it can be as slow as xslt to implement and more error-prone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a one-off process that you are just going to do the once and then throw away, then use whatever you are comfortable with and have the tools for. If you have more experience/tools for working with Java then go with that.

More generally, my experience has been on larger projects, we almost always end up resorting to java (even if we start development in xslt) - On bigger, ongoing projects, requirements often grown and get more complex and have generally found xslt transforms for large complex documents that has several nested levels (with list nodes) get unbearable to understand/test. Plus the inevitable requirement to have additional logic/conditional transformations/db lookups etc always crops up somewhere.

In the end, go with what you know!

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to **use the technology you are most familiar with**. You should not put too much effort into this because it is not a critical project - even the speed does not matter in this case.

You have certain options:

- XSLT
- Java SAXParser
- Java DOMParser + iterate
- Java StAX

Answer (score 1):

I'd have to go with XSLT, but ultimately the decision would depend on which tools you have available.

You could probably fairly trivially, using something like Dozer and/or Castor-XML write it in Java, which would be a good thing, if all you have is a Java IDE.

If you have a good XSLT tool (like XMLSpy) then XSLT would be the way to go.

So yeah. Depending on which tools you have, either could do this in a couple of hours (probably slightly more in Java if you need to first learn the frameworks).

Answer (score 1):

There is not enough information in this question to answer conclusively, so here are a few possible pointers.

If the job is simply to transform XML into another form of XML, with all the required data available in the original XML, then XSLT is likely to be the most appropriate.  After all, that is the entire purpose of XSLT.

If you have never used XSLT, don't want to learn it or don't have time to learn it, and are very competent in Java, then Java is likely to be the tool to use.  You will be quicker using a tool with which you are already familiar.

If the transformations require fetching data from some other source (e.g. a database), or doing some complex calculations, then you may have to use Java.

If the difference between the shapes of the two formats are great, then XSLT is likely to be a much clearer and easier way to perform the transformation.

If the differences are trivial, and you have very many documents to transform, then using the DOM in Java might be noticeably more performant.

Answer (score 0):

Java is a strong language and will give a strong support of thousands of API resources/documentation available. So if I were you I will definitely opt for Java.

Comment: But XSLT is purpose-designed for translating XML documents, so it's unlikely Java's rich framework would contain anything extra that would actually be a useful advantage.

Comment: using Java will give you the flexibility and strength whereas with XSLT it is not the case.